# What does the suffix -ling mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What does the suffix -ling mean. As in inkling...

Comment: It's a diminutive. _Duck, duckling; goose, gosling,_ etc. It's cognate with German _-lein_ diminutive suffix. In the case of _inkling_, it means 'the tiniest possible spot of ink', i.e, a small bit of evidence.

Comment: Yo, Lawler - put that as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The -*ling* in *duckling* or *gosling* is a diminutive, as mentioned by John Lawler.

But you've analysed *inkling* incorrectly. *Inkling* is derived from *inkle* + *ing*; the OED definition of *inkle* is 'to utter or communicate in an undertone or whisper, to hint, give a hint of'.